# MySQL Round() function won't round down

Tags: mysql, rounding

Im running MySQL version 5.5.3. 
I have this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT model, round(avg(overallRating),1)
FROM car_ratings, car_details
WHERE car_ratings.carId = car_details.carId
AND make = 'HOLDEN'
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY avg(overallRating) DESC, model ASC
```

This gives me the average rating of each model within 'Holden' make vehicles. It works fine except it rounds the number 4.050 up to 4.1. Is there a way of making this number round down? So that it gives me 4.0 instead of 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to round down in all scenarios? If so, you're looking for FLOOR

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor

```
SELECT DISTINCT model, FLOOR(avg(overallRating) * 10) / 10 -- HERE
FROM car_ratings, car_details
WHERE car_ratings.carId = car_details.carId
AND make = 'HOLDEN'
GROUP BY model
ORDER BY avg(overallRating) DESC, model ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It wasn't quite what i was looking for, but since i using mySQL with Python, i was able to get the result i wanted in Python.